# Jquery find characters in string and apply a custom class

Tags: jquery, css, regex, string

[image: Typographic challenge]

**Update:**

In order to achieve the typography above, i will have to use some jquery / css trickery.

First, I will have to create a class `.underlined` to set a background image, to have total control of the underline. *Unfortunately just setting a border-bottom, won't do the job because it will use the x-height of the font.*

Second, I will have to **find specific characters** like the **lowercase g** within the string and remove the `.underlined` class or apply an additional class for that specific character.

Now how do i match the g,j,p,q,y in a string and apply a class on it?

It should be similar to this, but then use a reg exp or something?

http://jsfiddle.net/hMEHB/2/

I tried the `:contains` selector, but i had trouble splitting up the string and putting it back together.

Comment: Sir, your question is not clear

Comment: I'd use standard javascript `.test()` to match the string and do the rest form there

Comment: Agreed with dude above. Do you want to highlight part of element innerHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the markup in your fiddle, I believe you want something like this:

```
var descenders = {"g": true, "j": true, "p": true, "q": true, "y": true};
$('a').each(function (i, elem) {
    var self = $(elem),
        textNodes = self.text().split(''),
        i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i += 1) {
        if (descenders[textNodes[i]]) {
            textNodes[i] = '<span class="descender">' + textNodes[i] + '</span>';
        } else {
            textNodes[i] = '<span class="underline">' + textNodes[i] + '</span>';
        }
    }
    self.html(textNodes.join(''));
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hMEHB/15/

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks, that was exactly what i wanted to achieve. Weird that html / css doesn't support better styling on underlines tho.

Comment: A slight revision of the above (though it's not necessarily any better, just a slightly-alternative approach): http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hMEHB/17/